# Assertion fails for collections.deque

Tags: python, assertion, deque

I can't see why I get an assertion error for the following code. It looks to me like the output from the print statement should be equivalent to the return value of `queue_challenge()` but not so. Can someone please explain why, and what the correct assertion should be?

```
from collections import deque


class Queue:
    def __init__(self):
        self.items = deque()

    def is_empty(self):
        return not self.items
        # return len(self.items) == 0

    def enqueue(self, item):
        self.items.append(item)

    def dequeue(self):
        return self.items.popleft()

    def size(self):
        return len(self.items)

    def peek(self):
        return self.items[0]

    def __str__(self):
        return str(self.items)


def queue_challenge():
    q = Queue()
    q.enqueue("Learning")
    q.enqueue("is")
    q.dequeue()
    q.enqueue("great")
    q.enqueue("fun")
    q.dequeue()

    return q


print(queue_challenge())  # deque(['great', 'fun'])

assert queue_challenge() == deque(['great', 'fun'])
```

Comment: You can''t directly compare a deque and a Queue

Comment: Can you tell me how they should be compared?

Comment: `queue.deque == deque`?  Or you could override `Queue.__eq__` to check is the comparand(?) was a `deque`, but that's arguably not very OO

Comment: I can see that q is an instance of Queue which is an instance of deque. In principle it seem reasonable to think they might be comparable, but I can also see why they might not be. I'm not sure how to go about writing an appropriate assertion though.

Comment: *"Queue which is an instance of deque"* `Queue` HAS-A deque (composition) but it's not true that it IS-A deque (inheritance).

Comment: @RobinAndrews "I can see that q is an instance of Queue which is an instance of deque." that is not correct. Queue is not an instance of deque.

Comment: Yes I can see that now. q has an instance of deque as one of its properties.

Comment: OK, so its' easily solved by returning `q.items` instead of just `q`.

Answer (score 1):

The `__eq__` can be overwritten as follows to test for the kind of equality you may be looking for:

```py
class Queue:
    # omitting the other methods of the class for succinctness
    ...

    def __eq__(self, other) -> bool:
        items = (
            other.items
            if issubclass(self.__class__, other.__class__)
            else other
        )
        return self.items == items

print(queue_challenge() == deque(['great', 'fun']))
True
```

Answer (score 1):

A `Queue` can't be compared with a `deque` because a `Queue` is not a `deque`, it wraps a `deque` (as [slothrop](https://stackoverflow.com/users/765091/slothrop) correctly [observed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76899717/assertion-fails-for-collections-deque?noredirect=1#comment135566127_76899717), it's a "Has-A" relationship).

You can override `__eq__` to use the internal `deque` if it finds that it is being compared with an actual `deque`, but this isn't ideal for a few reasons:

- it leaks `Queue`'s implementation details to the outside world. If you were to decide to swap `Queue`'s `deque` for some other type it would be problematic if there was a lot of client code comparing `deque`s with `Queue`s.
- Users of your code may be surprised to find that `Queue`s can compare equal to things that aren't `Queue`s.
- The comparison is too limited.  If a `Queue` can be compared to a `deque`, why can't it be compared to other ordered containers like `list`s or `tuple`s?

For these reasons, personally I would give `Queue` some kind of `matches_collection` method that lets you compare the `Queue`'s contents with other containers without placing too many restrictions on either side of the comparison, something like (untested, not production-ready etc):

```py
from collections.abc import Sequence
class Queue:
    ....

    def matches_collection(self, collection):
        # TODO strings :-)
        if not isinstance(collection, Sequence):
            raise TypeError(f"Can't compare Queue with {type(collection)}")
        return list(self.deque) == list(collection)
```